# fabricjs programmatically pan canvas on mobile browser

Tags: fabricjs

I have a website with fabric and it renders fine a pdf(as images). with mobile browser it displays fine and I enabled allowtouchscrolling and can pan the image (almost equal to scroll but not as effective as scrolling) . I have annotations on the image rendered which user has to respond. as of now its tedious to find each annotation object. Is there a way I can programmatically pan the fabric canvas centered to a specific x,y?

thanks 
prem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pan canvas so that `[0,0]` appears in center of viewport.
   To achieve this do `canvas.absolutePan(new fabric.Point(-canvas.getWidth() / 2, -canvas.getHeight() / 2)`
2. And then additionally offset canvas to your object coordinates (in my example I use `[left,top] + [halfWidth, halfHeight]` to calc offset of object center.

Thus conclude making [canvas.absolutePan](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#absolutePan) to `[-canvas.getWidth() / 2 + obj.left + obj.width / 2, -canvas.getHeight() / 2 + obj.top + obj.height / 2`

Working example you may find here: http://jsfiddle.net/mmalex/2rsevdLa/

```js
function panTo(canvas, obj) {
    let w = canvas.getWidth();
    let h = canvas.getHeight();

    let targetX = obj.left + obj.width / 2;
    let targetY = obj.top + obj.height / 2;

    canvas.absolutePan(new fabric.Point(-w/2+targetX, -h/2+targetY))
}

function recenterCanvas() {
    panTo(canvas, refRect);
    canvas.bringToFront(refRect);
    canvas.renderAll();
}
```